# Create a grid point layer from a text file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have an ASCII file (.txt) with the following columns:

```
ID, long, lati, value
```

Where `long`, `lati` are the coordinates (long/lat) of the cell centres of a LAT/LON grid with resolution of 30 arc seconds.

How can I create a shapefile with the grid points using the above text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'Add Delimited Text File' (It has the icon of an apostrophe).

You then specify the lat/long coordinates in the x/y fields and those points will be rendered. You then right click the layer and save as a shapefile.